# Why was Driftmark castle built in an inopportune location?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

House Velaryon's ancestral [Castle Driftmark](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Castle_Driftmark) is built on a spot on the island of Driftmark which is damp and tends to get "flooded" (I would guess slightly flooded on one side). Now, we know the island has nicer areas which don't get flooded by seawater (otherwise it would not be [arable](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Driftmark)).

So, what made the Velaryons choose a low-lying, wave-wind-and-salt-facing, location for their castle?

PS - The Velaryons later built a second castle, [High Tide](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/High_Tide), which isn't on the arable part and in fact is occasionally almost separated from the rest of the island.

Comment: I don't have a book cite, but frequent flooding wouldn't be fun for a besieging force.

Comment: @ceejayoz: There's no sense in laying siege to a castle on a small island. If you've even gotten them holed up in the castle, then they've lost their navy, so you can basically go away.

Comment: Maybe they've got the last dragon eggs in existence, or the true heir to the throne, or something else you can't just let them get away with.

Comment: @ceejayoz: So you're saying the Velaryons built their castle assuming they will get hold of the last dragon eggs or true heir to the throne or what not, and would be under siege because of that?

Comment: I'm saying sometimes there's a reason you want to besiege a castle until it falls... and inhabitants want to build it so that's hard to do.

Comment: Well I am not sure if explicit information is available however Velaryons are an old house who settled there even before fall of Valyria. Maybe the location wasn't so bad back then when they built their castle, presumably centuries before they started facing the flooding problems